# How do I open another component using Angular without displaying the first one?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new to the Angular world and hope that this question makes sense:

Say I have a section under app.component.html:

<**section** id="zoo">Zoo<**/section**>

Now I create another component (zoo) using the following command:

**ng g c** zoo

This will create 4 new files for zoo.

What I want now is to click on the section (zoo) that will redirect me to the created zoo-page and ONLY display the content for that page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please share the source code files involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new route like this `{ path: 'zoo', component: ZooComponent }`.
Then change your html for `<section id="zoo" routerLink="/zoo">Zoo</section>`

Comment: Hi Juaasca, thanks for your comment but I have tried that. It's displaying the content for both app.component.html and zoo.component.html. I only want to display the content for zoo.component.html upon selection.

Comment: You need to implement router outlet. Are you implementing it?

Comment: app.component.html is always displayed, because it have <router-outlet></router-outlet> right? You need an app.routes.ts or something similar, it depends of angular version, to render your custom components. For more information https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: With some screenshots of your tree project we could help you easier

Comment: Hi Richard, yes I have implemented router outlet.

I'll share some screenshots below for you to understand better:

My code for app.component.html:

<section id="zoo" routerLink="/zoo">Zoo</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


app-routing.module.ts:

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'zoo', component: ZooComponent }

];

Comment: Hi Juaasca, I would have shared the screenshots of how the home screen looks but StackOverflow won't let me since I need 10 points or something like that :(

Comment: Ok I just understand your problem. You need create another route like this { path: "section", component: SectionComponent } and use this route as main route in your app (this is unnecessary but it's good to know), then put a <a routerLink="/zoo"> inside section.component.html so wualah, magic.